Prove that the sum of residuals equals zero in simple linear regression
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\section*{Prove that the sum of residuals equals zero in simple linear regression}
Considering the simple linear regression model:
[
Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i + \epsilon_i, \quad i = 1, 2, \ldots, n,
]
where the residuals are defined as:
[
e_i = Y_i - \hat{Y}_i,
]
prove that:
[
\sum_{i=1}^n e_i = 0.
]
I understand that this is a property of the least squares method, which minimizes the sum of squared residuals:
[
\sum_{i=1}^n e_i^2.
]
However, I am unsure about the step-by-step mathematical derivation that leads to the conclusion that the sum of residuals is zero. Could you provide a clear explanation and breakdown of the proof?
\subsection*{What I’ve tried:}
\begin{itemize}
    \item I’ve reviewed my class notes and understand that this relates to the optimization process for finding \( \hat{\beta}_0 \) and \( \hat{\beta}_1 \).
    \item I’ve also looked into some online resources, but I couldn’t find a detailed explanation of why this property holds.
\end{itemize}
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
\end{document}

Please format the question so that it's readable on this site.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
